# Defining Function Macros with multiple steps

Tags: c

I know that you can define a function like this:

```
#PRINT printf("hello world\n");
```

Is it possible, instead, to define a function like this?

```
#PRINT printf("hello world\n"), printf("hello stack\n");
```

(... where the function has two steps to it.)  Is this possible?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/cpp/multistmt.html

Comment: That doesn't look like C.

Comment: Are you thinking of `#define PRINT printf("hello world\n")` etc?  Did you try using the second version?  What happened?  Have you learned about the comma operator?  It's doable, though whether it's a good idea is a separate discussion.  See also [Why use apparently meaningless `do … while (0)` and `if`…`else` statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros)  Consider using `inline` (better, `static inline`) functions rather than macros. Note that you should not normally end a `#define` with a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the above comments. I figured out the answer to my question.

To define a macro with multiple steps you need to do this

```
    #define FOO {\
                     printf("hello world\n");\
                     printf("hello stack\n");\
                 }
```

Calling FOO will then execute those two print statements.